# Can't figure out how to modify this oracle query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've got a query over here that I need to modify, but I can't figure out how.

I only want to show the color (aka `kleur`) where `aantal_planten` is lower than five.

Any suggetions?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT kleur, COUNT(plant.plantcode) AS aantal_planten
FROM plant, offerte
WHERE plant.plantcode = offerte.plantcode
GROUP BY kleur;
```

[Here's the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POSzf.png)

Comment: Add `HAVING COUNT(plant.plantcode) < 5`

Comment: Well... I quess..... Sometimes.... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The answer to your question is a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT kleur, COUNT(p.plantcode) AS aantal_planten
FROM plant p JOIN
     offerte o
     ON p.plantcode = o.plantcode
GROUP BY kleur
HAVING COUNT(p.plantcode) < 5;
```

Also notice that table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: hey Gordon, Just out of curiosity why ask  specifically to use explicit join syntax, comma with an alias also would do the job.. is there any performance benefits?

Comment: @Dawn . . . No performance benefit.  Just the same reason that we speak modern English rather than Middle English.